# SOQL lookup Event and relations in same query

Tags: soql, event

Say I have an event ID, and the goal is to get the event data and the names of every contact associated with the event in the `EventRelation` object.

Currently I look up the event record with the event ID from the `Event` object and run a separate query on the `EventRelation` object (also with event ID), and for each matching row in `EventRelation`, lookup the relation ID in the `Contact` object to get the contact names.

Basically this is a lot of calls, is it possible to do this all in one query?

Comment: query on evenrelation and learn about polymorphic soql to get parent Contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a relationship query:

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Relation.Name FROM EventRelations) FROM Event]
```

This will return Events and their Relations, if they have any.

Edit:

Updated to add example with relation information.

Comment: this will not retrieve contact names

Comment: @cropredy Yep I just edited after I realized I left out the Relation Information.

Comment: note that while Relation.Name works, if OP wanted Contact.Email or Contact.Phone, you'd need to use polymorphic SOQL

Comment: @NicholasSavini this seems to work well. How do you figure out that Relation.Name is what was needed? I tried running describe on the `EventRelation` object and there were no child relations.

Comment: @rosghub [In the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm), you'll find that the name of the relation field for Event Relation is RelationId. When using Relationship Queries, the Relationship name for a Standard field will be the field name without "Id". If it were a custom relationship, you would need to add "__r" to the end (ie Custom_Field__r). More information [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relationship queries like:

for **Normal Lookup fields**:

```
SELECT Amount, Id, Name, (SELECT Quantity, ListPrice,
  PriceBookEntry.UnitPrice, PricebookEntry.Name,
  PricebookEntry.product2.Family FROM OpportunityLineItems)
  FROM Opportunity
```

for **Polymorphic Lookup fields**:

```
SELECT 
  TYPEOF What
    WHEN Account THEN Phone, NumberOfEmployees
    WHEN Opportunity THEN Amount, CloseDate
    ELSE Name, Email
  END
FROM Event WHERE WHAT.TYPE in ('Account','Opportunity')
```

later in **Apex code**:

```
List<Event> allEvs = [SELECT id,custom_field1,
  TYPEOF What
    WHEN Account THEN Phone, NumberOfEmployees
    WHEN Opportunity THEN Amount, CloseDate
    ELSE Name, Email
  END
FROM Event WHERE WHAT.TYPE in ('Account','Opportunity')];
for (Event ev: allEvs) {
    if (ev.What instanceof Account) {
        Account acc = ev.What;
        System.debug('--acc--->'+ev.NumberOfEmployees);
    } else if (ev.What instanceof Opportunity) {
        Opportunity opp = ev.What;
        System.debug('--opp--->'+ev.CloseDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct in principle, but it would be stronger if it directly connected to _this_ question, which is about Event, EventRelation, and Contact.

Comment: @DavidReed
Here is a thought, if someone is much able to post a question on StackExchange, then I believe the same one can understand the solution as well. And if someone can't understand the logic or explanation from the answer then, then he/she should stop searching for the answer.